# Rails namespace root error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm running into a couple of errors when i try to define a root to a namespace. To recreate this, I'll rebuild a project from scratch.

```
rails new rails_test
cd rails_test
rails generate controller admin
rake db:migrate
```

Now I put some boilerplate in app/controllers/admin_controller.rb

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end
end
```

in app/views/admin/index.html.erb

```
<p>Index</p>
```

and finally in config/routes.rb

```
  root to: 'admin#index'
```

This all works perfectly, when i start the server and hit '/' (root) url (it goes to the admin index page), but it's not what I want.

This is meant to be part of a bigger project and I want to hit the /admin url and get the admin index so (following from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root) I change routes.rb to:

```
  namespace :admin do
    root to: "admin#index"
  end
```

but I get a routing error:

> uninitialized constant Admin

with a routes list containing 1 line:

> admin_root_path    GET     /admin(.:format)    admin/admin#index

My thinking from reading the end of this last line is that I'm already in the admin namespace so maybe i don't need to specify the controller index is in so I try changing routes to:

```
  namespace :admin do
    root to: "index"
  end
```

But that gives me an ArgumentError saying "missing :action" on the 'root to: "index"' line.

I can get around it by using scope, but it looks like using namespace is a bit cleaner and I want to understand whats going wrong here.

Ruby/Rails versions

```
ruby -v -> ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]
rails -v -> Rails 4.0.0
```

Any help is apprechiated

Answer (score 1):

`namespace` namespaces controllers as well. Change yours to

```
class Admin::AdminController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end
end
```

And move it under `app/controllers/admin`. That's what `admin/admin#index` means. :)

Comment: This does not seem to make any difference

Comment: Did you place it under `app/controllers/admin/` ?

Comment: I didn't but now that I have it works. But now my code is starting to get messy again. I had to move the view into /admin/admin/index.html.erb. The double admin here isn't a very nice pattern. Also, if I want to create a new page (show for example), in the namespace i have to write "get 'show' => 'admin#show'" instead of just "get 'show'" which i used to be able to do

Comment: Well... that's how Rails works. You don't really use route namespacing for something else than admin that often, and your controller name should be more specific to avoid that kind of duplication. As it goes for non-rest routes, again, it's rare, but if you have to use it, you want to specify the controller. You'll get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

According to  [rubyonrails.org guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)  you should be able to do something like this. 
it should looks like this

```
namespace :admin do
  root to: "admin#index"
end

root to: "home#index"
```

What do you get with rake routes?

Comment: This is the code I already have (apart from the home root, which shouldn't make any difference).

rake routes prints the same 1 route line i mention in my post

Comment: @MarkDunne  When I add `namespace :admin do
      root to: "admin#index"
  end` and i run `rake routes` and i grep for root i see `admin_root GET      /admin(.:format)                                              admin/admin#index` so your link should be `admin_root_path`

Answer (score 0):

on rails 4 in routes  two roots not permited now

use
get "/admin" => "admin/admin#index", :as => "admin"

Type in terminal

```
rails generate scaffold Admin::User username email

rake db:migrate
```

if only Controller type this

```
rails generate controller Admin::User
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is something like

```
namespace :admin do
    get 'other'
end

get 'admin' => 'admin#index'
```

This allows for the `index` and `other` methods to be in straightforward `AdminController` controller in usual directory, views to go in `views/admin` etc.

You could probably also use

```
resource :admin, only: [:index] do
    get 'other'
end
```